# Gas allowance geth

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, gas-price, gas-limit

I have deployed an Ethereum private network PoA with geth connecting 3 nodes: 2 nodes in aws EC2 instances and my own laptop. My purpose is to store strings in the network, so therefore, i have deployed the following Smart Contract:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract CRUDOptimizado {

```
// Variables de estado 
string[] data;

// Operaciones CRUD: CREATE, READ, UPDATE y DELETE:

// Operación CREATE
function createData(string memory _description) public{
    data.push(_description);
}

// Operación READ por búsqueda de la posición en memoria
function readData(uint _id) public view returns (string memory) {
    return (data[_id]);
}

//Operacion READ todos las entradas de datos
function readAllData() public view returns (string[] memory){
    return data;
}

//Operacion COUNT de todas las entradas de datos
function readcount() public view returns (uint){
    return data.length;
}

// Operación UPDATE
function updateData(uint _id, string memory _description) public returns (string memory){
    data[_id] = _description;
    return (data[_id]);
}

// Operación DELETE
function deleteData(uint _id) public{
    delete data[_id];
}
```

}

I have succesfully deployed an API with Express to interact with my Smart Contract methods. The following middleware calls the function "createData" from Smart Contract:
app.post('/post/file',async (req,res,next) =>{

```
    const file = JSON.stringify(req.files.file);
    console.log(file)
    //const buffer = req.files.file.data;

    const receipt = await contract.methods.createData(file).send({
        from: addressSender
    })
    res.status(200).json(receipt);
    
})
```

When I store huge JSONs (parsing them to strings in the API), I have problems with gas allowance. Geth console:
Served eth_sendTransaction                duration=470.274556ms       err="gas required exceeds allowance (50000000)"

Here is part of my genesis file (I have modified gasLimit):
{
"config": {
"chainId": 113,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0,
"istanbulBlock": 0,
"clique": {
"period": 3,
"epoch": 30000
}
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x62f60dbd",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cf9c875960822c4d232db99ac36f7cfbc66b07c70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x1fffffffffffffff",
"difficulty": "0x1",
....

Is there any way of modifying Geth max allowance (it is capping gas at 50,000,000)?
If it isn´t, is there any other private Blockchain with 0 gas price with documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the geth commandline options [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options). I think you're looking for `rpc.gascap`